# In Virgo-Server Import-Package could not be resolved.Caused by missing constraint in bundle constraint

Tags: java, spring, maven, jco

I am very new in Java Spring framework. I have created a custom bundle and want to deploy the jar/bundle in virgo server.But I am not able to successfully do so.

Here is my template.mf file screen , where I have added the dependency

[image]

Here is my java file , where I have imported the packages

[image]

Here is the original jar file screen

[image]

Here is my `pom.xml` where I have added the dependency

[image]

But once deploying the jar file after maven build (which throws no error ) I am constantly getting the error

```
Caused by:  org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'com.xyz.costfromsap.application' at version '1.4.0.RELEASE': Cannot resolve: com.xyz.costfromsap.application
Resolver report:
    An Import-Package could not be resolved. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <com.xyz.costfromsap.application_1.4.0.RELEASE>
         constraint: <Import-Package: com.sap.conn.jco; version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)">
```

Here is my updated dependency jar file after converting it to OSGI bundler

[image]

I have also updated the `template.mf` and `pom.xml`

[image] 
[image]

But still the issue persists.

Comment: Update your question with `pom.xml`, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `sapjco3.jar` is not an OSGi Bundle. It is just a plain old Jar file. You need convert it to an OSGi bundle. In Eclipse or any Eclipse variant follow the following steps. You can use `Import-Package` on only the packages which are listed in `Export-Package` in bundle `MANIFEST.MF`

New -> Project

[image]

Plugin from Existing Archive -> Add External and load your Jar and Click Next.

[image]

Give a name and Select an OSGi Framework radio button and Click finish.

[image]

Now you will have a new Project created. Go to `MANIFEST.MF` file and Runtime tab and Export Packages, Click Add button and select all the packages listed.

[image]

Finally your `MANIFEST.MF` should have `Export-Package:` with all the packages just as following.

[image]

And now Right Click on the project and Click Export and Select Java -> Jar File.

[image]

Select files to export. Ignore Eclipse specific files and pom files.

[image]

Click next until you see Manifest Selection and Select Use existing manifest option and select the `MANIFEST.MF` in META-INF in the project.

[image]

Click finish and Use that Jar in your Virgo server. Place it either in VIRGO_HOME/repository/usr.

Comment: Thanks Shazin for your help.While trying this, I have question for you how to understand if a jar is OSGI bundle or not ?

Comment: The way to differentiate is to look at the MANIFEST.MF file. An OSGi Bundle will definitely have Export-Package and optionally will have Import-Package if it has dependencies from other OSGi Bundles.

Comment: Hello Shazin still the issue persists ;(

Comment: If `symbolic name` should be `com.sap` here ? And that why its not able to identify the dependency jar .

Comment: Bundle name, symbolic name and version should be set according to your jar

Comment: Yes I have changed it to `Bundle-Name: com.sap.conn.jco` , `Bundle-SymbolicName: com.sap.conn.jco` and my jar name is `com.sap.conn.jco-1.0.0.jar` . But still no luck

Comment: Did you place it in VIRGO_HOME/repository/usr and restart the virgo server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75264/discussion-between-dibyendu-dutta-and-shazin).

Comment: finally it is fixed. The problem was with `MANIFEST.mf`  file. I have added the `version` against each `Export-Package` and its starts working .